# Load plugin.so error: Undefined symbol "mosquitto_client_username"

Tags: plugins, mosquitto

Why my plugin passed compile,but can't load from conf file?

```
mosquitto -c mosquitto.conf
1612271905: mosquitto version 2.0.5 starting
1612271905: Config loaded from mosquitto.conf.
1612271905: Loading plugin: /usr/home/bluse/mosquitto-pg-auth-plug/auth-plugin.so
1612271905: Error: Unable to load auth plugin "/usr/home/bluse/mosquitto-pg-auth-plug/auth-plugin.so".
1612271905: Load error: /usr/home/bluse/mosquitto-pg-auth-plug/auth-plugin.so: Undefined symbol "mosquitto_client_username"
```

compile command is:

```
cc -I/usr/local/include -I`pg_config --includedir` -L/usr/local/lib -L`pg_config --libdir` -lpq -fPIC -shared auth_plugin.c -o auth-plugin.so
```

Am I missing some thing?
Help!

Answer (score 0):

use mosquitto fixes branch, or use version v2.0.7